# How to list all bibliography entries in Bookdown without citing and changing title in HTML version?

Tags: html, r, latex, knitr, bookdown

I am using [bookdown A Minimal Book Example](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown-demo/). I want to make some changes in this according to my requirements. I wonder how to list all bibliography entries without citing them.

I tried `\nocite{*}` in `preamble.tex` (comes with *A Minimal Book Example*) but no effect. I could not also not figured out how to change top left title `A Minimal Book Example` in `html` version.

Comment: Did you try adding `\nocite{*}` at the end of the document, not in the preamble. 
It seem to work for me - I get all the entry from the minimal example

Answer (score 5):

To include references without citing them in-text, you can use the [`nocite` parameter](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html) in the [YAML header block](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html) in `index.Rmd`.

```
nocite: | 
  @R-bookdown, @xie2015
```

The YAML header block is also where you can adjust the book title, e.g.:

```
title: "Some new title here"
author: "Yihui Xie"
...
nocite: | 
  @R-bookdown, @xie2015
```

Comment: Thanks @Keith for your answer. I tried  `nocite: |   @R-bookdown, @xie2015`, but is not working. I know how to change the title of document and also tried to given code. But still it gives the same title "A Minimal Book Example"  on the top left above the toc bookmars in html version. Any thoughts. Thanks

Comment: Did you try deleting the output folder (in my case, `_book/`) to make sure that the book is re-rendered?

Comment: This works for me in rmarkdown but **not** in bookdown

Comment: @lowndrul thanks for this discussion, I used nocite: '@*' in teh YAML of teh index.Rmd i bookdown and it works as a charm. Please make sure you have .bib file which has the references.

I used in the last chapter # References the following code chunk: so all packages loaded are cited

```{r create_reference_list, include=FALSE}
write_bib(x = .packages()), file = 'packages.bib')
```

Answer (score 3):

The header of the menu (Book Title) is in "_output.yml"

Comment: Thanks @Pascal for helpful answer. Do you have idea how to list all bibliography entries without citing them? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I used `nocite: '@*'` in the YAML of the index.Rmd in bookdown and it works as a charm. Please make sure you have .bib file which has the references.

I used in the last chapter # References the following code chunk in order to cite all packages which are attached

````
```{r create_reference_list, include=FALSE}
write_bib(x = .packages()), file = 'packages.bib')
```
````

Details can be found here:

- [Unused References (nocite)](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html#Citation_Styles)
- [3.5.3 Add all items to
  bibliography](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/bibliography.html#add-all-items-to-bibliography)